# object is not iterable (Python and Django)

Tags: python, django, pdf

I try to put a html in pdf (I did, but there´s a problem). I get the error on the tittle ('Boletas' object is not iterable), someone know what's the problem here? I really would appreciate the help.

Views.py

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None 



class ListaBoletasListView(ListView):
    model = Boletas
    template_name = "home/boletas.html"
    context_object_name = "boletas"

class ListaBoletasPdf(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         boletas = Boletas.objects.all()  
         data = {
             'boletas' : Boletas
         }  
         pdf = render_to_pdf('home/listaBoletas.html', data)
         return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Models

```
class Boletas(models.Model):
    id_boleta = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fecha_boleta = models.TextField()  # This field type is a guess.
    precio_total = models.BigIntegerField()
    rut_persona = models.ForeignKey('Personas', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='rut_persona')
    id_pedido = models.ForeignKey('Pedidos', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_pedido')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boletas'
```

html file

```
<h1>Boleta</h1>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Id boleta</th>
        <th>Fecha boleta</th>
        <th>precio</th>
        <th>rut</th>
        <th>id</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for Boletas in boletas %}  <-------- "ERROR"
        <tr>
            <td> {{Boletas.id_boleta}}</td>
            <td> {{Boletas.fecha_boleta}}</td>
            <td> {{Boletas.precio_total}}</td>
            <td> {{Boletas.rut_persona}}</td>
            <td> {{Boletas.id_pedido}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I don´t use the for and endfor, there´s no error... sorry if I don´t explain very good to myself

Comment: Please paste stack trace of error. Also, which view is being called? And what is the name of the html file that you included in your question?

Comment: The view used is the one that is attached, same case for the html

Comment: You have multiple views in your views.py, which reference to different html files. Please specify which view is causing the error and the name of the html file you included in the question.

Answer (score -1):

In views.py

data= { ‘Boletas’: boletas }

Comment: The problem with that is that doesn´t  rescue the information from Boletas

Comment: actually it worked by changing the order inside the html, thanks for the help

Comment: Is this answer helps you?

Comment: @JeanMirandaCerda if this answer helped, the code in your question must not be accurate.